# List<string> Assigned to Separate Array

Tags: c#

I think this is overkill but want to ask.  The code below is being run, is there a need to assign the values of tempList to a totally separate array?  I feel that you could iterate the values of tempList but want to verify before I make a change:

```
List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
  try
  {
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
    {
      tempList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
    }
  }
  catch
  {
  }
}

reader.Close();
crMy = tempList.ToArray();

for (int q = crMy.GetLowerBound(0); q <= crMy.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
{
  return crMy[q];
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ? you are not iterating actually.you just returning the first value of the tempList.

Comment: Is it overkill to assign the 1st List<string> to a secondary crMy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need the array, your code could be changed to:

```
return tempList.First();
```

or `FirstOrDefault` depending on the code that follows.

Comment: beautiful - I thought it was overkill, but wanted to confirm b4 making a change that blew up in my face.

Comment: Should probably be `if(tempList.Any()) return tempList.First();` to match current behavior.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no need to initialize a new array. You can simply iterate over the `List<string>`.
Although you even need a List, because you are simply returning the first element in list. That will prevent you from reading every row, for example if you have 1 million entries you'll have to read them all, before returning the first one.

This code reads and directly returns the first non null value:

```
string result = null;
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
    while (reader.Read()) {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(0)) { 
            return resultreader[0].ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're correct that there's no reason to copy the List to an array in this particular context.

I would recommend using a using statement with your SqlDataReader however as it's a disposable object and I'm not seeing any dispose code here.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        try { if (!reader.IsDBNull(0)) { tempList.Add(reader[0].ToString()); } }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code returns the first column of the first row where that column is non-null. You could simply write this and avoid the list altogether.:

```
static string GetDataValue()
{
  using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your-connect-string-here"))
  using ( SqlCommand    cmd  = conn.CreateCommand() )
  {
    InitializeSqlCommand(cmd) ;
    conn.Open() ;
    using ( SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
    {
      while ( reader.Read() && reader.IsDBNull( 0 ) )
      {
        string value = reader[0].ToString() ;
        return value ;
      }
    }
  }
  throw new InvalidOperationException("no [useful] data returned");
}
```

That approach seems a little specious to me: you're returning potentially a lot of data, reading it all across the network and then throwing everything away except for the first column of the first row where that column is non-null.

You should modify the query to return just what you want, so instead something like this (rather open-ended) :

```
select t.col_1, t.col_2, ... , t.col_n
from foo t
```

change it to the more specific:

```
select top 1 t.col_1
from foo t
where t.col_1 is not null
```

Your RDBMS will thank you. Your network will thank you. Your code will run faster, your customers will be happier and and you can replace the query logic with the eminently simple and more intentional:

```
static string GetDataValue()
{
  string value ;
  using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your-connect-string-here"))
  using ( SqlCommand    cmd  = conn.CreateCommand() )
  {
    InitializeSqlCommand(cmd) ;
    conn.Open() ;
    value = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar() ;
    conn.Close() ;
  }
  if ( value == null ) throw new InvalidOperationException("no data read") ;
  return value ;
}
```